# Cant find my application in list after implementing alias Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I want my application to sometimes behave as the home launcher and sometimes not to. In order to do this I implemented an "alias- activity" that will behave as the "home launcher activity" (see below manifest).

After toggling between enable and disable there are times where I cannot see the aplication in the list of applications(I declared the Launcher in the intent-filter). However, after restarting the device I am able to see the application in the list...very wierd...

I am toggleing between both activities by the following code :

Enable Activity:

```
ComponentName enableHomeActivityManifest = new ComponentName(HOME_PACKAGE,HOME_PACKAGE
            + ".activities.HomeActivity");

    mContext.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(enableHomeActivityManifest, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Disable alias:

```
    ComponentName componentToDisable = new ComponentName(this, MessageDispatcher.HOME_PACKAGE + ".aliasHomeActivity");
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentToDisable,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        );
```

Manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".aliasHomeActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:targetActivity=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement for the home screen launcher to automatically reload its icons based upon changes in component state. While that would be ideal, there is no question that many home screen implementations do not do this.